# How to make Vim autosize to terminal dimensions?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make vim select the number of columns and lines based on the terminal size?

For example, if I connect over SSH using Putty and the terminal happens to be 100x100, can vim autodetect this and size itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found this is not happening automatically? I've never seen Vim *not* resize itself.

Comment: Probably something with your terminal settings (`$TERM` etc.) is wrong; applications usually query the size from it; Vim, too. Does this only happen with Vim, or also with other apps (like `nano`)?!

Comment: Since this is a programming site, if you find any issues, perhaps you could submit a patch? Start looking here: https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/term.c#3029